# Facebook Authentication only in Android and Blackberry?

Tags: android, authentication, facebook

I have a mobile application and will like to have the authentication implemented either through the Application itself or through Facebook username and password.

For example, if I have username and password of Facebook then one can login into the Application. I don't want to integrate the facebook completely only the authentication part. Is this possible?

Hope to get a quick response.

Regards

Sunil

Answer (score 1):

You can use de [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), I used an implementation based on FBConnect for Android, but last thursday was released the [Facebook SDK for Android](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/), now that implementation would be more easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this as in this project: http://code.google.com/p/triker/. Just don't ask for offline access in mobile app code (remove it from fb url get). When your backend get authcode You will know that user has FB account. If You wish You can exchange that code to auth token on server to get access to users data.